# In AHK, what is the difference between Try/Catch and OnError()? When to use one or the other?

Tags: error-handling, autohotkey

I am currently writing an AHK script that reads and writes files.
I would like to handle the possible I/O errors,
but the doc isn't clear to me regarding *wether I should use* **Try/Catch** *or* **OnError()**.

What is the **difference** *between the two*? And **when to use** *one or the other*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some more research, here is my understanding:

- **Try/Catch**: Use it to:

  - **Specifically identify certain lines of code over which it will be applied.**
  - **Then, if you would like, proceed with the execution.**
  - *A Try/Catch allows to proceed with the execution of the command after the Try block that failed.*
  - *(But, a Try/Catch **does not** allow to proceed with the execution of the command after the one that failed **within** the Try block. For example if 5 commands are wrapped, then if the 2nd one threw, it will not be possible to proceed with the execution from the 3rd after doing something in the Catch-block.)*
- **OnError()**: Use it to

  - **Deal with any unhandled error.**
  - **Block (or not) the default error dialog.**
  - **In any cases the thread execution is stopped after you handled the error.**
  - *There can be multiple OnError() handlers active at a time,
    and you can decide, in which order they will be executed (or to stop the execution after any one of them) when an error occurs.*
  - *If all handlers return 0 all handlers are called one after the other, then the default error message is displayed, then the thread exits.
    If any handler returns a non-zero integer, the thread exits without calling the following handlers and without displaying the default error dialog.*